# R ftable revised

Tags: r

everyone,
 In R, there is a ftable. If the row variable are more than two, is it possible to put the first row in the first block, second row in the second block as show in the following table?

```
       Income
Sex  Higher Lower
Male    12  23
Femle   11  21

MaritalStatus       
Married 10  20
Single  13  24
```

Comment: This looks like you just have two separate tables: `table(df$sex, df$income)` and `table(df$married, df$income)`.

Comment: thanks, is possible to put together?

Comment: There's `rbind`, but you lose the labels.

Comment: it works well. are there anyway to add row names? thanks.

Comment: See `?rownames`.

Comment: thanks. but how? appreciate your help.